# C# #region in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there in Ruby something equivalent to `#region` (C#)?

> ### [#region (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx)
>
> *`#region` lets you specify a block of code that you can expand or collapse when using the outlining feature of the Visual Studio Code
>   Editor. In longer code files, it is convenient to be able to collapse
>   or hide one or more regions so that you can focus on the part of the
>   file that you are currently working on. The following example shows
>   how to define a region:*
>
> ```
> #region MyClass definition
>     public class MyClass 
>     {
>         static void Main() 
>         {
>         }
>     }
> #endregion
> ```
>
> [source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx)

Example of C# code with `#region`


[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-U3xXd7aOsZY/TvxJbfGIbVI/AAAAA]
(image from article ["Make your code Speak by using C# Region" by Pranay Rana](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/438830/Make-your-code-Speak-by-using-Csharp-Region))

Thanks!

Comment: Please try to make questions as self-explanatory as possible without having to visit external links, since those are prone to become inaccessible with time. In this case, it'd have been nice if you would've demonstrated what a C# region is and what you're trying to achieve with them :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand `#region` correctly, it is a purely cosmetic tool dividing code into sections that can be visually collapsed. As far as I know, Ruby has no such feature. If you're going to find any such functionality, it is probably going to be part of an editor (e.g., [code folding in IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/8.0/folding-and-expanding-custom-blocks.html?origin=old_help)) and not part of the Ruby language itself.

Comment: yes #region is a kind of cosmetic. It helps to make code more readable.

Comment: Ruby has many ways of organizing code: methods, classes, mixins, files. That's more than enough. In general, Rubyists prefer to write simple, well-factored, well-designed, readable, concise, expressive code that simply doesn't need such features in order to be understandable.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, your comment is very good and useful. Please publish it as answer to my question.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I think your comment is generic and doesn't really add any information to the question at all, since all programmers, be it Ruby, JavaScript or C# strive for simple, well-factored, etc etc code.